# Java Developer Kit 32-bit

Tags: java

Есть проблема, я хочу скачать jdk, но у меня 32 битная версия ОС.
Где можно скачать эту версию jdk или на oracle просто не нашел?
Слышал что можно как то с x86 провернуть, но что-то мало верится.

Answer (score 4):

Разницы между операционными системами Windows x86 и x32 просто нет — обозначают они 32-битную систему. Если вопрос как-то вас коснулся, стоит запомнить, что разрядность операционных систем может быть только 32 или 64 бит, а x86 это абсолютно то же самое, что и x32.
Можете почитать [тут](https://thedifference.ru/chem-otlichaetsya-windows-x86-ot-x32/) подробнее.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle JDK существует только для 64-разрядных систем начиная с Java 9. Вам придётся либо использовать более раннюю версию, либо собрать JDK под интересующую платформу самостоятельно, используя исходный код OpenJDK.

Comment: Интересно, не знал, +1 вам)